# Native iOS menu via Compose Muliplatform?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I using Compose multiplatform for my app and im trying to reach native menu for android and iOS.

I tried to create iOS-native menu view using expect-actual functions.

```
expect class CategoriesMenu(
    categoriesMap: Map<String, Boolean>,
    enabled: Boolean,
    onMenuItemClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    @Composable
    fun CategoriesMenu(modifier: Modifier)
}
```

here is my actual realisation for iOS:

```
actual class CategoriesMenu actual constructor(
    val categoriesMap: Map<String, Boolean>,
    enabled: Boolean,
    private val onMenuItemClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    @Composable
    actual fun CategoriesMenu(modifier: Modifier) {
        val myMenu = UIMenu.menuWithTitle("Categories", children = categoriesMap.keys.toList())
        val button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeSystem).apply {
            setTitle("Test", UIControlStateNormal)
            setMenu(myMenu)
        }

        UIKitView(
            modifier = modifier,
            factory = {
                button
            }
        )
    }
}
```

line `setMenu(myMenu)` triggers an error `Thread 1: "-[__NSCFString _mutableCopy]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`